# Scaling using ScaleTransform with inverted Y Axis

Tags: c#, wpf

My XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True">
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
MouseWheel="Grid_OnMouseWheel">
<Grid.RenderTransform>
<ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
...
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

My Code:

As you can see, I need the Zero Y Coordinate in the bottom Left hand Corner:

```
private void Grid_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{

UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
Point position = e.GetPosition(element);

double Width = element.RenderSize.Width;
double Height = element.RenderSize.Height;

Matrix GridMatrix = GUIGrid.LayoutTransform.Value;

if (e.Delta > 0)
{

ScaleFactor += 1;

ScaleTransform Transform = new ScaleTransform(ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor, position.X, position.Y);
Transform.ScaleY = -ScaleFactor;
GUIGrid.RenderTransform = Transform;
}
else
{

ScaleFactor -= 1;

if (ScaleFactor <= 0)
ScaleFactor = 1;

ScaleTransform Transform = new ScaleTransform(ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor, position.X, position.Y);
Transform.ScaleY = -ScaleFactor;
GUIGrid.RenderTransform = Transform;
}
e.Handled = true;
}
```

My Problem:

I do not get the right Coordinates and my zoom flies off the screen. I have tried setting -Y as the Position, but this is not enough. If someone could please explain why this is not working as I expect?

Answer (score -1):

Well, no as simple as I had hoped and documentation poor!

```
ScaleTransform Transform = new ScaleTransform();
Transform.Value.ScaleAtPrepend(ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor, Position.X, Position.Y);
Transform.ScaleX = ScaleFactor;
Transform.ScaleY = -ScaleFactor;
GUIGrid.RenderTransform = Transform;
```

Now working as I expected.